# how does jenkins ui show log files?

Tags: spring, reactjs, user-interface, jenkins

Currently I am developing an application that exposes file contents especially of log files with spring-boot to a web-app driven by react.

I really like the log view of jenkins and asked myself how they are handling this. Unfortunately I couldn't find the log viewer in the source code.

Can someone please give me a hint how they are updating the file on server and client side or just give me their source?

Answer (score 1):

## Custom log view implementation might not be required

Spring boot has a special endpoints called **actuator api**

One of this endpoints is : /actuator/logfile which is used to view the spring boot log :

`curl 'http://localhost:8080/actuator/logfile' -i -X GET`

[image]

---

## how they are updating the file on server and client side

- Update log file in server is not our problem.
- A cool view in web is our concern.
- I used a node.js implementation. Is ready to use and you could take some ideas:

  - https://github.com/mthenw/frontail
- I think a combination of web sockets, css and a correct file stream operation (open, close) and memory management, could be necessary to reach your goal.

Comment: spring-actuator is not what I need. Theres only the possibility to expose one file. I want so see a folder and click one of the 10 logfiles.

Thanks for the frontail!! Will help maybe

But again, how does jenkins actually do this?

Comment: You might review spring boot actuator to implement new endpoint which will receive a log file path.

Comment: Do you mean to the build log of jenkins?